# Dynamic properties name in PHP

Tags: php, html, string, codeigniter, object

There is an object in PHP named `$item` , and in this object I have properties of

```
title , title_cn, title_tw
```

And I would like to create an function that auto generate the properties based on the language, so I coding like this:

```
<?= $item->title . set_lang(); ?>
```

And the function:

```
function set_lang() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $lang = $CI->session->userdata('site_lang');
    if ($lang == "english") {
        return "";
    } else if ($lang == "zh_tw") {
        return "_tw";
    } else if ($lang == "zh_cn") {
        return "_cn";
    }
}
```

However, the name is not generated correctly, it is just the $item->title append with the string of lang code, e.g. `my title 1234_tw,  titleABC_cn` etc...

How to dynamic generate the properties ? Thanks fo helping

Comment: Search for variable variables

Comment: Var vars are easy to understand once you get them ;P But they are not needed in this case unless you want to shorten the code making it more difficult to understand ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first concatenate `$item->title` onto `set_lang()` and place that in a variable.

You can then use that variable to call the right property on the obj.

**example**

```
$itemLangTitle = $item->title . set_lang();

echo $item->$itemLangTitle
```

You can use variables as properties dynamically but be careful with user input as always!

On a sidenote you also need to make sure the property exists otherwise you'll get errors. So make sure that if this doesn't yield anything it should fallback to english naming or something unobstructive ;)